# My custom option not working on Right panel on view page

Tags: magento

I am working on a Magento store, the requirement is to move the custom option to right panel.

I already did it, by moving some lines in catalog.xml file.

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <!--
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
                -->
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                    <label>Alert Urls</label>
                </block>

                <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                    <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
                </block>                

            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
        <!--#####################################################-->
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
                        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>




        <!--#####################################################-->    



            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

Now it is on right panel and price change also working fine,

But the problem is that when i am going to submit it by select one

it showing me an error like "`Please specify the product required option(s).`"

this is for unable to take the attribute vale.

like size `(XL, XXL)`

If any one know this, please help me thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the options block appeares out of the main product form, and validator highlights you an error after submitting the form.

**The solution**

Do not move the options block out of the "product.info" block in layout, because this block contains the main product form. You need to modify *catalog/product/view.phtml* template to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, i am not getting it .Can you Please Post it with the changes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be done only in layout xml, so you have to change template catalog/product/view.phtml to be able to display "product.info" block in two columns. 

Perhaps, the editing of 2columns-right.phtml is also necessary. Don't use block "right" as container for options.

Comment: thanks bro , can you please share any post with me or any programmatic help for me ,it will be appreciate

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to edit the files of your theme to be able to get the following results: 

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1osaiZRPPPDauup7CIN3j1syIod2oyN-p4k_KP9OpMCc/pub?w=960&h=720

Compare it with the default Magento theme layout: 

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1vWA87n7tvcat5aShuMBWx5i1XCCz9qnslAKpaC_7poI/pub?w=960&h=720

Unfortunately, I can't share the exact pieces of code here, because it is a huge amount of theme coding.